# Configuracion del autoload

Tags: php

Tengo que implementar la clase Autoload en mi proyecto con la funcion spl_autoload_register. Como no me funcionaba trate de probarlo en un codigo mas simple. Tengo tres carpetas en mi mini proyecto: Una llamada Config, donde esta la clase AUtoload.php

```
<?php namespace Config;
    class Autoload {
        public static function iniciar() {
            spl_autoload_register(function($classPath)
            {
                $ruta = ROOT .  $clase . ".php";
                print $class;
                echo '<p>' . $class  . '</p>';
                include_once($class);
            });
        }
    }
?>
```

Una carpeta Modelos donde tengo una clase llamada Persona que solo quiero que diga hola

```
<?php namespace Modelos;
    class Persona
    {
        public function hola()
        {
        echo 'La persona dice hola';
        }
    }
?>
```

Y en el index inicio el Autoload, instancio una nueva persona y le ejecuto el metodo hola.

```
<?php
    define('ROOT', __DIR__ . "\\");
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    require('Config/Autoload.php');

    Config\Autoload::iniciar();

    $persona= new \Modelos\Persona();
    $persona->hola();
?>
```

Me tira este error:

C:\wamp\www\prueba_autoload\Modelos\Persona.php
( ! ) SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
( ! ) Fatal error: Class 'Modelos\Persona' not found in C:\wamp\www\prueba_autoload\index.php on line 12
Call Stack

Que es la línea donde instancio la nueva persona.
Toma a la clase como Modelos\Persona, y no como la clase Persona. Es decir mete el nombre de la carpeta o del namespace dentro del nombre de la clase. No busca Persona sino "Modelos\Persona" como una clase.

No entiendo como resolverlo.

Comment: Lo cambie a lo que me decis y sigue tirando error 

C:\wamp\www\prueba_autoload/Modelos/Persona.php
( ! ) SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
( ! ) Fatal error: Class 'Modelos\Persona' not found in C:\wamp\www\prueba_autoload\index.php on line 12

Comment: Mira la edición de mi respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Tendrías que ponerlo de esta manera:

```
$persona= new \Modelos\Persona();
```

ya que de esta manera si que estás haciendo referencia al namespace en la que de verdad está tu clase. Si no pones la contrabarra justo antes de `Modelos` entonces lo está tomando como si la clase estuviera en el namespace actual.

Por otro lado, el `Config\Autoload` si que te lo está cogiendo porque has importado el fichero directamente en tu index.

Esta explicación la puedes leer en la documentación de PHP [aquí](http://php.net/manual/es/language.namespaces.faq.php#language.namespaces.faq.full) y [aquí](http://php.net/manual/es/language.namespaces.faq.php#language.namespaces.faq.qualified).

**EDIT:** El problema ahora es que no te encuentra la ruta. Esto se debe a que estás cambiando las barras invertidas de la ruta por barras así: `/` en esta línea:

```
$ruta = ROOT . str_replace("\\", "/", $clase)  . ".php";
```

No hagas el replace ya que si no la ruta no te la va a coger ya que va a tener barras invertidas `\` y barras normales `/`.

Comment: Entonces deberia quedar asi?
spl_autoload_register(function($classPath)
            {
                $ruta = ROOT . $clase . ".php";
                print $class;
                echo '<p>' . $class  . '</p>';
                include_once($class);
            });

Comment: @merisavino Eso es.

Comment: Ahi edite la pregunta, se cual es el error pero no se como resolverlo. Muchas gracias!

Comment: @merisavino Vale. ¿Has probado a hacer `$persona = new Persona();`? Sin ningún include ni nada.

Comment: Sip, tampoco funciona! :(

Answer (score 1):

Te olvidas de usar / implementar la clase:

```
use Modelos\Persona; //<-- !!

$persona= new Persona(); // <-- Sin el namespace
$persona->hola();
```

**EDIT:**

Para ser mas concreto:

Supongamos que tienes tus rutas de esta manera:

```
root
|
|__ Modelos // Carpeta Modelos
|      |
|      Persona.php // Tu clase Persona 
|
autoload.php
index.php
```

**autoload.php**:

```
<?php

spl_autoload_register(function($className) {

    $path = __DIR__.'/'.str_replace('\\', '/', $className).'.php';

    // Por si acaso, comprueba si existe ese archivo
    if (file_exists($path)) {
        require $path;
    }    
});
```

**index.php**

```
<?php

require __DIR__.'/autoload.php';

use Modelos\Persona; // Usar la clase Persona

$persona = new Persona();
$persona->hola();
```

Comment: Pero la gracia del autoload segun pide mi profesor es no usar ni requerir mas clases al principio de ningun archivo php, para ellos los namespaces y demas, para luego borrar todos los require! Entiendo que si pongo use es como si pidiera incluirlo ahi y en controladoras y demas lugares, con lo cual no tendria sentido el autoload, no?

Comment: @merisavino - He actualizado mi respuesta y así no deberías tener ningún problema

Comment: Aldanux, me exprese mal,  me refiero a que no deberia usar include o require de la clase, tampoco 'use' que entiendo que es similar... Es decir, segun mi profesor, con el autoload justamente deberia evitarse los require, los 'use' y los 'include'.

Answer (score 1):

Mil Gracias a todos, el error estaba en la definicion de Root

```
define('ROOT', __DIR__ );
```

Luego, la funcion del Autoload quedaria asi:

```
spl_autoload_register(function($classPath)
        {
            $class = ROOT . "/" . str_replace("\\", "/", $classPath)  .          ".php";
            //echo '<p>' . $class  . '</p>';
            include_once($class);
        });
```

Muchisimas gracias a todos!

Comment: Me alegro mucho de que lo hayas solucionado :) ¡Muchas gracias por compartir tu respuesta! +1